# Nutch regex-urlfilter is not working

Tags: solr, nutch

I am crawling a website it has lot of sub domains. I want to restrict couple of urls from crawling. 
For Example i have a website http://www.123.com and i have sub urls ends with http://.123.com. I want to avoid http://www.def.123.com and http://www.ghi.123.com from crawling how can i add the filters.

Currently i applied the filter below but its crawling those two restricted urls

> +^http://*.123.com
>
> -^http://www.def.123.com
>
> -^http://www.def.123.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
+^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?123\.[a-zA-Z0-9.\S]+$
-^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?def\.[a-zA-Z0-9.\S]+$
-^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?ghi\.[a-zA-Z0-9.\S]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comment at the start of the regex-urlfilter.txt says:

> The first matching pattern in the file determines whether a URL is included or ignored

So since your first regex matches, and it starts with a +, all URLs from this site will be crawled.
To fix this, put the more specific (exclude) URLs first, and the general rule last.

Comment: I tried in both ways but urls are not injecting into the crawler

-^http://www.def.123.com
-^http://www.def.123.com
+.
+^http://*.123.com
___________________________________ 

-^http://www.def.123.com
-^http://www.def.123.com
+^http://*.123.com

Comment: It's difficult to analyze your problem like that. I can think of two suggestions:
1. Did you remember to run ant runtime after the change?
2. You can run nutch with a specific command to test your filters. It may be helpful to try that while playing with the content of the file, to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
+^https?://(?!(www.def|www.ghi).123.com(/.*)?$).*.123.com(/.*)?
```

This will accept any url that starts with the `https?://.*.123.com` pattern, except `https?://www.def.123.com` and `https?://www.ghi.123.com`.

Comment: Thanks for the Response.Its doesn't works for me. When i applied this filter the urls are not injecting.

Comment: I edited my answer. It should work properly now. I also added the `s?` rule after the `http`, just in case the site you are trying to crawl uses `https` (in addition to the `(/.*)?` rules that I added.

Answer (score 0):

order is important try the following

-^(http|https)://.*.123.com

+^(http|https)://123.com/ or +.